# I applied for a CSQ which got canceled. What should I answer under the question about previous visa/immigration applications?

Tags: canada

I applied to the Quebec Immigration Service for a CSQ a few years ago but didn't continue and my application got canceled automatically (refused with an *intention to refuse* with a deadline that passed). Now if I want to apply to get a Canadian *study permit* (which is made at the Federal level), what should I answer under the question "**Have you previously applied to enter or remain in Canada?**" in **IMM94**?

Comment: The first two words in your question are "I applied". Therefore the correction answer to "Have you previously applied (...)" must be "yes". How could it be otherwise?

Comment: @HenningMakholm if the OP didn't "continue" and the application was therefore "canceled automatically", it is possible that the Quebec government considers that the application was never actually completed. This sort of thing happens all the time with multipart online forms. If you fill in Page 1, then click the Next button, and then close your browser without hitting "Submit" at the bottom of Page 2, the system may consider you to have never Submitted anything.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: The OP says in the **two very first words** in his question that he did in fact apply. If he now tells the Canadian government that he _did not_ apply, then either he will be lying to them, with whatever disastrous consequences that can have, or he lied _to us_ in his question and therefore cannot really expect a useful answer. You're proposing a story where he did not submit a partially filled-out online application -- in that case he **did not apply**, and you're saying we might be in the case where he's lying to us in his question.

Comment: I think the distinction is between understanding if the Canadian government considers an abandoned, incomplete application the same as a completed one.

Comment: For future readers: I would have said no. Your CSQ application (Certificat de Selection de Quebec) is not a VISA application, it is a prerrequisite for a VISA application when coming to Quebec.